# Eclipse 2019 Hanging after Git Clone Repository & Branch Selection

Tags: eclipse, git

I am running Eclipse 2019-06. All the SSH2 settings with the Keys have been specified under `Window > General > Preferences > Network Settings > SSH2` . A private Key was generated in Eclipse, and then uploaded to my github.com Profile.

I am trying to clone a Git Repository.

First, note that the initial connection to Git succeeded, because I'm showing all my branches.

**After clicking Next, Eclipse hangs.**

[image]

Just to be sure, the keys have been generated and exist in the *.ssh* folder as shown.

[image]

And this key, titled "Eclipse 2019 Key," has been uploaded to my profile on GitHub.com

[image]

Comment: How long is it hanged? Eclipse might take several minutes when in picky mode :D. I mean get a coffee and be back after 5' at least. Then you can declare it a hang :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **a bug in Eclipse 2019-06** in **Windows 10**.
Documented here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1099477/

It started working in Eclipse 2019-**03** (the prior release).

Incredible!

Comment: That's already fixed in the nightly build (update site: [`https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly`](https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly)), isn't it?

Comment: I don't know about the nightly builds, I downloaded the official latest installation available from the official site, and it was there. Cost me a day.

Comment: Please check if Eclipse 2019-06 with the nightly build of JGit/EGit (_Help > Install New Software..._) works. I'm not able to reproduce this issue. Therefore, I assume it occurs under very specific conditions.